# MySQL Replace characters in every table and column of a database

Tags: mysql, string, replace

I'd like to replace a string in every column and every table of a specific database. Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: That is because I have spotted Gibberish at some locations and it will take me days to fix it one by one

Answer (score 1):

Not without doing some programming.
The most simple approach would be to use show/describe commands in your favorite language and run on the result set (names of columns/tables) and create from that a list of UPDATE queries to run on your DB.

Why don't you write it and Open Source it, you are not the first to look for something like that (Or google it, there might be a script ready somewhere).

Answer (score 1):

Found this answer from another thread:

http://www.anovasolutions.com/content/mysql-search-and-replace-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this myself when we changed domain on our Wordpress website. It can't be done without some programming so this is what I did.

```
<?php  
  header("Content-Type: text/plain");

  $host = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $database = "mydatabase";
  $string_to_replace  = 'old.example.com';
  $new_string = 'new.example.com';

  // Connect to database server
  mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);

  // Select database
  mysql_select_db($database);

  // List all tables in database
  $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM ".$database;
  $tables_result = mysql_query($sql);

  if (!$tables_result) {
    echo "Database error, could not list tables\nMySQL error: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
  }

  echo "In these fields '$string_to_replace' have been replaced with '$new_string'\n\n";
  while ($table = mysql_fetch_row($tables_result)) {
    echo "Table: {$table[0]}\n";
    $fields_result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table[0]);
    if (!$fields_result) {
      echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
      exit;
    }
    if (mysql_num_rows($fields_result) > 0) {
      while ($field = mysql_fetch_assoc($fields_result)) {
        if (stripos($field['Type'], "VARCHAR") !== false || stripos($field['Type'], "TEXT") !== false) {
          echo "  ".$field['Field']."\n";
          $sql = "UPDATE ".$table[0]." SET ".$field['Field']." = replace(".$field['Field'].", '$string_to_replace', '$new_string')";
          mysql_query($sql);
        }
      }
      echo "\n";
    }
  }

  mysql_free_result($tables_result);  
?>
```

Hope it helps anyone who's stumbling into this problem in the future :)